# QT Creator - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide6' : CONSOLE ERROR

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt-designer, pyside6

whenever i try to run my ui file on QT Creator, it says:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide6'

[image]

It was working, I did projects before but I upgradeded some stuff and it doesnt work now.

Python311 file:

[image]

Python3832 file:

[image]

Does it happen because 3832 has pip3.8 but 311 has 3.11?
When i tried to upgrade the pip inside of 3832, it says:

[image]
When i tried to add pyside6 to 3832, it says:

[image]

My projects were working with only these yellow paths. I added blue ones to see if this was the reason of the error but it is not because QT still gives the same error.

[image]

Please help, I have homework :(

I tried to run my ui file but It gave 'module not found error' but I have the module. Probably it cant find the path but I also added the path to the system. So, I cant find a solution by myself :(

edit date: 20.01.2024
i got error again after upgrade
i wrote pyside6-uic form.ui -o ui_form.py
and that worked idk how

Comment: I found the solution and solution is so simple. I just clicked the 'Debug' > 'start debugging' > 'start debugging of startup project'. it downloaded all of the essentional stuffs and it's working rn. please someone close the question for me cus site doesnt let me to do it. I can delete the question ofcourse but It wont be usefull for the other people so I want it to stay as archive at least.

Comment: Closing the question isn't the right move here. Either delete it (IMO it's not very clear and isn't very likely to help future users) or accept your self-answer. But in that case, other people can still submit answers moving forward.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution and solution is so simple. I just clicked the
'Debug' > 'Start Debugging' > 'Start Debugging of the Startup Project'

It downloaded all of the essential stuff, and it's working.

Comment: Accepting this as the answer is the right move -- there's no reason this couldn't help someone else who is new to running things in Qt Creator.